# Creating team doesn't upload originally selected image. Had to reupload

Tags: discussion, bug, old-teams, developer-story

I'm not sure if this is a bug on the "Developer Story" team or the "Teams" team or both.  On my developer story I saw my current work experience and underneath it it said something to the effect of:

"Would you like to create a team for this organization".

So I clicked on yes...while doing this it asked for a logo to upload for this company.  So I uploaded a 60x60 png.  Should this not have carried over to the team?

Also when adding a logo to the same company should it not carry over to the same company across the various experiences?  For instance, I have the following:

[image]

I added the logo (in blue)...but the company is the same across my other experiences as well (note the senior software engineer entry to the left of it).  Should it also go and take this image across the same company or should we be going to each "Experience" (thankfully I only have 2) and upload the same image each time?

Sorry I mentioned I'd stop with the bug reports - but I just cannot!